Oracle - select sorted rows with filter and export to csv: how to parallel execute job? start_id/end_id are page offsets, not columns
I want to filter, sort and dump data from a big table to a csv. Oracle 12c.

unload does filter but does not sort, but I want a stable sorting as I need to compare the data with files from other sources. Also it does not chunk output files. Of course if someone knows how to do this in unload please tell.
dp is the same as unload right?
expdp does not exist in the db; not installed?
I am exploring how to do this with DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE package but I cannot find how to. The reason is simple: I want to chunk the rows by page, not by any column.

The main query I want to execute is:
select FIELD1, FIELD2
      from DATA
      where COMPANY_ID like :regex
      order by FIELD1   -- indexed and unique
      offset :start_id rows fetch next :page_size rows only;

I only want 2 column.
I think I cannot use CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL or CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_ROWID as

I don't think I have a continuous number column after filtering. The doc of CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL says:


This procedure chunks the table (associated with the specified task) by the specified column. The specified column must be a NUMBER column. This procedure takes the MIN and MAX value of the column, and then divides the range evenly according to chunk_size.


and this table does not use physical rowid.

First question:
Can I use PK? The PK is NUMBER, and continuous; but filtering by COMPANY_ID will make it not continuous. So for example from ID 0 to 500 I only need 2 rows, that breaks the job right? Will it fetch 2 for me or 500?
Second question:
I am following https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2#user_defined_framework but I don't know when the chunk is executed and scheduled.
My code:
create or replace procedure compare (
  dir varchar2, 
  regex varchar2, 
  start_id integer, 
  end_id integer, 
  page_size integer
) as
   CURSOR c_query is 
      select FIELD1, FIELD2
      from DATA
      where COMPANY_ID like regex
      order by FIELD1
      offset start_id rows fetch next page_size rows only;
  output   utl_file.file_type;
  filename varchar2(100);
begin
  filename := 'split_' || start_id || '_' || end_id || '.csv';
  output := utl_file.fopen ( dir, filename, 'w' );
  utl_file.put_line ( output, 'FIELD1,FIELD2' );
  
  for row in c_query loop
    utl_file.put_line ( output, row.FIELD1 || ',' || row.FIELD2 );
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose ( output );
end compare;
/


create or replace procedure loop_comparison(
    l_task     VARCHAR2 := 'test_task',
    regex VARCHAR2 := '90%',
    page_size  NUMBER := 50,
    dir varchar2 := 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'
)
  as
    l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_sql_step_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
    row_count  NUMBER;
    p_start    NUMBER := 0;
    p_end      NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => l_task);

  select count(ID) into row_count from DATA where COMPANY_ID like regex;
  
  p_end := page_size;
  
  l_sql_stmt := 'BEGIN compare(''' || dir || ''',''' || regex || ''', :start_id, :end_id, ' || page_size || '); END;';
  WHILE p_start < row_count
  LOOP
    l_sql_step_stmt := 'select ' || p_start || ' as start_id, ' || p_end || ' as end_id from dual';
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_sql(task_name  => l_task,
                                                sql_stmt    => l_sql_step_stmt,
                                                by_rowid    => FALSE);

    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => l_task,
                                   sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
                                   language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                   parallel_level => 20,
                                   job_class      => 'test_task_class');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(
           TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
        || '  '
        || DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task)
    );
    p_start := p_start + page_size;
    p_end := p_end + page_size;
  END LOOP;
end loop_comparison;
/

After exec loop_comparison, I find this:
SQL> select task_name, chunk_type, status from USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS;

   TASK_NAME    CHUNK_TYPE     STATUS
____________ _____________ __________
test_task    UNDECLARED    CREATED

SQL> select * from USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS;

no rows selected

I suppose it's never running.

If you are doing an ORDER BY, then you will be passing over the entire set of rows that match you criteria anyway, so its unlikely to see any massive benefit from splitting this up, unless the dominant cost is the sorting element.
If that is the case, I'd tackle that, eg, bumping up PGA or having faster TEMP tablespace IO.
'dp' is datapump, so not appropriate for csv.
Because you are sorting by FIELD1, then if you know some upper/lower limits for FIELD1, then you could use that for chunking/sorting because by definition each chunk will have mutually exclusive data.  You'd probably end up with differing file sizes.
If you want to use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE for chunked strings, you can have a lookup table, eg
ID  LO   HI
--  ---  ---
1   AAA  FZZ
2   GAA  QZZ
3   RAA  ZZZ

and then create three chunks with CREATE_CHUNK_BY_SQL to load values 1-1, 2-2, 3-3 as tasks.
Then the SQL or PLSQL that does your work (ie, the routine that DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE will schedule) will do
select ...
from   my_table, lookup_table
where  field1 >= lo and field1 < hi
and    lookup_id = :startid
order by field1


Thanks. FIELD1 contains only digits, but column type is varchar. Could you elaborate how to use that for chunking?
Also about bumping up PGA could you explain a little bit more? I would ask DBA but they seem want me to do all the coding, including the procedure, even I am on developer side.

And the first paragraph you said parallel running will not benefit me, instead I should select+filter+order once, and insert into a temp table and unload that table right?

After posting the question, I came up with another solution: chunk by column ID(as it's NUMBER and should be continuous) and do my query in each chunk. Do you think it will be faster?

If you want to sort by FIELD1 you would have to chunk by FIELD1 to ensure that each chunk is in order (and hence can be concatenated without further sorting).  If FIELD1 is (say) 5 digits, then you could chunk from 00000-20000, 20001-40000 and so on for 5 parallel chunks

Yes, if FIELD1 is a number, then it's doable, but it's not, it's varchar. I don't think it could be used by CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL method; meanwhile ID is NUMBER and can be understood by CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL. If I have to sort again, then I sort again afterwards... But I doubt it would help with the performance.

One level of indirection is all you need.  Have a table with a numeric (say 1 to 5) and then low/high pairs of potential FIELD1 values.  I'll add it to the answer

OK now I understand, I can chunk FIELD1 manually and filter with the ranges I created in the auxiliar table. That is one option yes. I didn't know I could do between N and M with a varchar field. The problem may be at last deciding which are the min and max values of FIELD1, as it keeps updating.

Hm thanks. I may try that and come back; DBAs were using unload on the production machine saving csv file there, it turns out much faster then select and spool onto my local machine; and considering production data should stay in production, at last we may just unload; though your answer is valid option.

The approach of @ConnorMcDonald is valid and I have accepted that, but after that I tried to chunk on ID column which is a NUMBER column PK with CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL and it worked. I use ID between start_id and end_id as range, search in that range the rows I want, so each chunk is independent with each other.
One thing to note is that in the loop_comparison I need to use two single quotes to escape one single quote, in order to put literal values into the statement. q syntax didn't help me.
The updated version of procedures:
create or replace procedure compare (
  dir varchar2,
  regex varchar2,
  start_id integer,
  end_id integer,
  page_size integer
) as
   CURSOR c_query is
      select FIELD1, FIELD2
      from MYUSER.DATA
      where COMPANY_ID like regex
      and ID between start_id and end_id -- "between" is both end inclusive, but -1 has been done while chunking
      order by FIELD1;
  output   utl_file.file_type;
  filename varchar2(100);
begin
  filename := 'split_' || start_id || '_' || end_id || '.csv';
  output := utl_file.fopen ( dir, filename, 'w' );
  utl_file.put_line ( output, 'FIELD1,FIELD2' );

  for row in c_query loop
    utl_file.put_line ( output, row.FIELD1 || ',' || row.FIELD2 );
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose ( output );
end compare;
/

create or replace procedure loop_comparison(
    l_task     VARCHAR2 := 'test_task',
    regex VARCHAR2 := '97%',
    page_size  NUMBER := 100000,
    dir varchar2 := 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'
)
  as
    l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task (task_name => l_task);
  
  -- will check min and max of ID column, and chunk by page_size;
  -- chunk 1: min                   -> min + chunk_size * 1 - 1;
  -- chunk 2: min + chunk_size * 1  -> min + chunk_size * 2 - 1;
  -- ...
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL(task_name  => l_task,
                                                      table_owner    => 'MYUSER',
                                                      table_name => 'DATA',
                                                      table_column => 'ID',
                                                      chunk_size => page_size);

  -- concat real values and single quotes together, dealing with char types manually
  -- seems double single quotes escaping is better, q syntax may not be what we want
  l_sql_stmt := 'BEGIN compare(''' || dir || ''',''' || regex || ''', :start_id, :end_id, ' || page_size || '); END;';

  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => l_task,
                                 sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
                                 language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                 parallel_level => 20);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(
         TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
      || '  '
      || DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.task_status(l_task)
  );
end loop_comparison;
/

I run it like:
exec loop_comparison;

It did all the jobs and generated me 1092 files, in total 30 million rows of data in 1 min. Much faster than unload by DBA(8G data in 15 min).
